# QuickBooks. Filtering items by LinkedTxn

Tags: quickbooks, qbxml

I would like to get the ItemReceipt items that have LinkedTxn  with the PurchaseOrder type. 
Now I use the following query:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><?qbxml version="12.0"?>
<?qbxml version="12.0"?>
<QBXML>
    <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="continueOnError">
        <ItemReceiptQueryRq requestID="1">
            <IncludeLineItems>true</IncludeLineItems>
            <IncludeLinkedTxns>true</IncludeLinkedTxns>
            <OwnerID>0</OwnerID>
        </ItemReceiptQueryRq>
    </QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
```

The query returned all ItemReceipt items, and I filtred them on the client. 
Could you tell me if there is a way to create a filter that returns only items that have LinkedTxn with the PurchaseOrder type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The QuickBooks SDK does not support a way to create a filter that returns only items that have a LinkedTxn with a certain type.

You'll have to pull all of the transactions, and then filter them within your app.